# If $G$ is finite of odd order, then the product of all its elements, in any order, is an element of the commutator subgroup $G'$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, derived-subgroup

This is **Exercise 3.36** of Roman's *"Fundamentals of Group Theory: an Advanced Approach"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cprod_%7Bg%5Cin%20G%7Dg%5Cin%20G%27%24&p=7), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

**Neither semidirect products nor presentations are covered in the book so far.**

> **Definition:** The *commutator subgroup* or *derived subgroup* $G'$ of a group $G$ is the subgroup of $G$ generated by all commutators $$[a,b]:=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$$ (for $a,b\in G$). A group $G$ is *perfect* if $G=G'$.

### The Question:

> If $G$ is a finite group of odd order, then the product of all its elements, in any order, is an element of the commutator subgroup $G'$.

### Thoughts:

If $G$ is abelian, then $$\prod_{g\in G}g=e\in G'$$ trivially.

If $G$ is perfect, there is nothing to prove.

By Lagrange's Theorem, $G$ has no involutions, so there are no elements $x\in G$ such that $x=x^{-1}$.

Putting the identity to one side, then, elements come in pairs: $y$ and $y^{-1}$. Let's separate $G$ into any $\frac{n-1}{2}$ elements $g$ in a set $P$; and their inverses $g^{-1}$, a set $N$. Note that $P\cap N=\varnothing$. Now one product of all elements of $G$ is of the form

$$e\left(\prod_{g\in P}gg^{-1}\right)=e\in G',$$

for any order of the elements of $P$.

So much for the theoretical approach . . .

---

Consider when $G=\Bbb Z_7\rtimes \Bbb Z_3$, given by the presentation

$$\langle a,b\mid  a^7, b^3, bab^{-1}=a^4\rangle,$$

which I believe to be the smallest, nonabelian group of odd order, according to [group names](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/index.html).

Here $G'\cong \Bbb Z_7$, again, according to [group names](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/1/C7sC3.html).

The elements of $G$ are of the form $a^ib^j$ for $i\in \{0,\dots, 6\}$ and $j\in\{0,1,2\}$. Again, taking the identity aside, there is, essentially, up to $20!$ different products of all elements of $G$; there might be subtleties that lower that upper bound, but still: it's a lot: that's what I'm getting at. Consider $[a^{\alpha_1}b^{\beta_1}, a^{\alpha_2}b^{\beta_2}].$ This is looks like it would be messy to compute in abstraction. There ought to be a slick way of doing this.

Please help :)

Comment: $G$ doesn't have odd order.

Comment: That's a typo, @ChrisCuster; thank you for pointing it out. I've edited it now.

Comment: Ok.  Looking at it, I figured you meant $\Bbb Z_7\rtimes\Bbb Z_3$.

Comment: That's an interesting fact.  I didn't know that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $G/G'$ is abelian, the image of the product of elements in any order by the quotient map $G\rightarrow G/G'$ is the neutral element of $G/G'$, a fact that you have noticed